# Problem detecting iPad userAgent in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, ipad, safari

I have a problem detecting iPad in Safari. My aim is to make all iOS mobile devices have link to AppStore, while desktop has link to the browser version of app. I've already tested it on iPhone and iPad Chrome - everything worked correctly, though in Safari iPad is treated as Mac device.

I've tried other solutions from related stackoverflow topics, such as finding maxTouchPoints, trying 'ontouchend' in window etc. But nothing works.

Currently I have the following function, where I check iOS in userAgent and also checking on touch points value, but it doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but maybe there are more progressive solutions to this problem.

```
export default function CheckDevice() {

  if(typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    let os = null;
  
    
    const isIpad = /Macintosh|Mac OS|MacIntel|MacPPC|Mac68K/gi.test(userAgent) && (navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0);
    const isIOS = isIpad || /iPad|iPhone|iPod/gi.test(userAgent)

    if (/Macintosh|MacIntel|MacPPC|Mac68K/gi.test(userAgent) && navigator.maxTouchPoints === 0) {
      os = 'Mac';
    } else if (isIOS) {
      os = 'iOS';
    } else if (/'Win32|Win64|Windows|Windows NT|WinCE/gi.test(userAgent)) {
      os = 'Windows';
    } else if (/Android/gi.test(userAgent)) {
      os = 'Android';
    } else if (/Linux/gi.test(userAgent)) {
      os = 'Linux';
    }
  
  return os
  }
```